# Round the inside corner edge by sketch

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way to round the corner like this using Sketch? I am very new.
Can anyone teach me or it's actually not good to use Sketch practice icon design?:)  Thank you.

This is what I want to achieve. 
[image: Goal - like using handler in illustrator]

However, I tried few times on Sketch but I got this sharpe edge inside like this:
[image: My work]

Comment: I don't have sketch but after the first Google result I have a pretty solid idea what to do. Can you elaborate on what you have tried so we maybe can spot the error?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. My steps in sketch: draw circle > draw a line > use subtract > path > scissors > so now I have the pic as the above attached screenshot. I then tweaked it with the function(straight, mirror, disconnected) but these don't seem to get what I want for that result from the illustrator from the website. Thank you. : )

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I used.
[image]
1. Create Circle
2. Create Rectangle overlapping area you want to subtract
3. Use subtract tool
4. Flatten shape
5. Layer -> Paths -> Close Path
6. Double-click the half circle to view the anchor points
7. Add anchor points on each side of the half circle just above the ones on the bottom
8. Select each anchor point on the bottom and set the mode to straight instead of disconnected
9. set the corner radius for each side
10. Profit